# Resolve cyclic dependencies when doing type annotation on python

Tags: python, type-hinting

Imagine that I want to have 2 python classes in 2 .py files creating only one python module so that I can have

```
#in the file A.py inside the folder ModuleX
#Some imports go here I GUESS
Class A:
    def defExA(self, var1:ClassB)
        Some_code()
```

and

```
#in the file B.py inside the folder ModuleX
#Some imports go here I GUESS
Class B:
    def defExA(self, var1:ClassA)
        Some_Code()
```

And

```
#create the file __init__.py inside the folder ModuleX
#Some imports I guess in order to do what I need
```

The problem resides that in order to do type hinting I need to import A and B on A and B and then I have cyclic dependencies.
In the end I would like the hinting working and if it is possible maintain the files separated because they can actually be quite large.

I create a repository with the same problem here:
https://github.com/TiagoMRodrigues/type_hinting_cycles

Comment: The general solution for such things is to lift the circular dependency items into a parent class, and derive both A and B from that one.  Does that not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

afterall in the PEP484 is reference something called forward reference that is exactly what I needed. I updated the code in GITHUB if example is needed.

https://github.com/TiagoMRodrigues/type_hinting_cycles